# How add a new extention?

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have a simple project of viewer on NodeJs: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-nodejs-tutorial with some basic exstention. I want to know how can I add the new extention from https://github.com/jeremytammik/forgefader to my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ForgeFader is based on React and uses ES6 syntax, One way to get started will be taking a look at the React Boiler plates we have in order for you to start getting familiar with it. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-react-boiler.nodejs

After you are able to use this, you will be able to start checking the extension code in order to be able to use it in your project, It will require some work on your side, unfortunately this is not a plug and play extension like the ones used in the basic NodeJs tutorial.

Jeremy has done a great work documenting all his steps in the readme of the Fader repo you already have, I would suggest going over it.